# Does spark zipWithIndex keeps the order of lines when reading multiple files from s3

Tags: apache-spark

I'm loading multiple files from s3, for example

```
s3://bucket1/111
s3://bucket2/222
...
```

Assume file 111 has lines

```
line0
line1
```

and file 222 has lines

```
line2
line3
```

I'm planning to use

```
sc.textFile("s3://bucket1/111,s3://bucket2/222...").zipWithIndex()
```

to load all these files and add index to each of the lines.

My questions is whether the index will be based on the order of files as well as the order in the same file for the lines in the same file.

I would like the orders to be like

```
(line0, 0)
(line1, 1)
(line2, 2)
(line3, 3)
...
```

Comment: Why don't you try it out if it does or not?

Comment: I tried and it works as I expected. But I want to make sure every time it gives me the same result other than I was just lucky

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it does. When in doubt check debug string:

```
scala> sc.textFile("README.md").zipWithIndex.toDebugString
res0: String =
(2) ZippedWithIndexRDD[2] at zipWithIndex at <console>:25 []
 |  README.md MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at <console>:25 []
 |  README.md HadoopRDD[0] at textFile at <console>:25 []
```

No shuffle (single stage) means order is preserved. Storage implementation doesn't matter.